# trying to compare dates with momentjs

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, momentjs

i am getting x amount of dates from my mysql database, then i am passing them as a parameter in momentjs moment() function and i want to compare only the year month and day, but i don't know how to format momentjs and compare it with my current date.
this my code :

this code doesn't work if you could help me

```js
earnings:async function(req,res){
        var earnings = {
            daysGain:0, //ganacia del dia
            grossProfit:0, //ganacia bruta
            netProfit:0,    //ganancia neta
        }
       var user = req.user;
        if(user){
            const payments = await Payment.findAll().catch( err =>{ return res.status(500).send({err:err}) })
            if(payments && payments.length > 0){
                let now = moment();
                payments.forEach( pay => {
                    if( moment(pay.createdAt).isSame(now).format('YY/MM/DD'))
                }); 
                console.log(now,"now");
            }
        }else return res.status(403).send({message:"you are not logged in "});
    }
```

when the dates match my current day I want to add a certain value to my pay object

note : im using sequelize orm this one generate colum cratedAt and updateAt automatically

Comment: hellllp pleaseeee

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use the right formatting insie moments default method to achieve the same. Here is a sample code snippet for your reference

```js
const dates = ["21/03/2021", "15/09/2021", "10/12/2021"];
dates.forEach((date) => {
  const current = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  if (moment(date).isSame(current)) console.log("Matched Date", date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```